# $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{a^2+b^2}$ if $(a,b)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I hope to show that
$$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{a^2+b^2}$$
for $(a,b)=1$.

I made an effort to find a homomorphism but I failed.

Can you give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $(a,b)=1$ if and only if there exist integer $m,n$ such that $an+bm=-1$.

Incidentally, the result should be that $$\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)\cong\Bbb Z_{a^2+b^2}.$$

Comment: Could you explain me more precisely? I can't get the homomorphism with an+bm=-1

Comment: I don't have time to get into the details, I'm afraid, but specific instances of this sort of question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/157059/28900), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23358/28900), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1507534/28900). Hopefully that's enough to give you the idea of what such a homomorphism should look like.

Comment: @Pearl: Let me know what you're able to do with those, and if you're still stuck, I'll try to explain it further when I have the time.

Comment: Thank you for link. It is easy to solve with starting from $Z$ to $Z[i]/(a+bi)$. I first thought from $Z[i]$ to $Z_{a^2+b^2}$ ^0^

Comment: You're very welcome!