# $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(a^2+b^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers, is the following assertion true?
$$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(a^2+b^2).$$
My idea is to define $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[i]\to\mathbb{Z}/(a^2+b^2)$, $x+yi\mapsto\overline{bx-ay}$, it is obvious that
$$\phi((x+yi)+(u+vi))=\phi(x+yi)+\phi(u+vi).$$
But I have difficulty with verifying that $\phi$ keeps the multiplication, i.e., $\phi((x+yi)(u+vi))=\phi(x+yi)\phi(u+vi)$ and how about the kernel of $\phi$?

Comment: Note that your map sends $i$ to $\overline{-a}$, which is not in general a square root of $-1$.  So it doesn't respect the multiplication.

Comment: Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{a^2+b^2}$ if $(a,b)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564077/mathbbzi-abi-cong-mathbbz-a2b2-if-a-b-1).