# Prove that (3) is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Prove that (3) is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and thus $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3)$ is a field. (Hint: for $a+bi\not\in(3)$, show that $(a+bi,3)=(1).)$ How many elements are in this field?

We've only recently learned about maximal ideals so my understanding of them is quite poor, I'm having a tough time approaching this question. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: $3$ is prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$, which is a PID, so that $(3)$ is a maximal ideal. The quotient has $9$ elements, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564077/mathbbzi-abi-cong-mathbbz-a2b2-if-a-b-1). You will find all you need on this site MSE here. Start searching for it.

Comment: If you know the concept of Euclidean Domain it should be pretty straight forward (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) using the argument posted from @Dietrich Burde.

Comment: Two tools that are useful, norm $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Euclidean_division). Assume that you have $(3)\subset I\subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Take $x\in I\setminus (3)$ and compute its remainder $a+bi$ modulo $3$. We must have $a^2+b^2=|a+bi|<9/2$. The only options for $a,b$ are $\pm1,0$. All of them give $a+bi$ either units or $0$. In the first case $I=\mathbb{Z}[i]$, since it would contain that remainder that is a unit. In the second case we get that $x\in(3)$, which contradicts that $x\notin (3)$.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(3,x^2+1) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2+1)$

Comment: Well, we could get remainders $2+0i$ or $0+2i$ too. But in that case, divide $3$ by these to get remainder $1$. In this case we got $1\in I$, which implies $I=\mathbb{Z}[i]$.