# Generator/generators for cyclic group $\mathbb Z[i]/(11-8i)$, given the following isomorphism:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, gaussian-integers

I need to find a generator for $V$, being $V$ the $\mathbb Z[i]$-module generated by $v_1,v_2$ where:

$(1+i)v_1 + (2-i)v_2 = 0$

$3v_1 + 5iv_2 = 0$

[EDIT] To clarify $V = \frac{\mathbb Z[i]^2}{A\mathbb Z[i]}$ where A is the traspose matrix of coefficients of the system above. Then $V$ is the $\mathbb Z[i]-$module presented by $A$

I have come to the conclusion that $V \cong \mathbb Z[i]/(11-8i)$ by calculating Smith´s form of the matrix formed from the traspose of the coefficient matrix from the system above.

Given a cyclic group, e.g. $\mathbb Z/(3)$; I know that the element $[1]$ generates de whole group, because $[1]$ has order $3$ there, and I wonder if, using this logic, $[1]$ generates the cyclic group mentioned above ($\Bbb Z[i]/(11-8i)$).

Once I know this, I know the only thing I´ve got to do to find a generator for $V$; is apply the inverse isomorphisms, which would only be a matter of calculus.

I could really use some help, thanks beforehand!

Comment: @DietrichBurde because we would call a group cyclic, when it is isomorph to another group with one and only one direct factor in its form according to the first theorem of structure. (At least is what I have understood)

Comment: We have $\Bbb Z[i]/(11-8i)\cong \Bbb Z_{185}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564077/mathbbzi-abi-cong-mathbbz-a2b2-if-a-b-1/564106).